# Homotopy fibers in the Joyal model structure and the Kan–Quillen model structure

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

While playing around with $\infty$-categories, I ran into the following problem:

> Let $p:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ be a functor of $\infty$-categories. Does one of the following condition imply the other?
>
> (A) The homotopy fibers of $p$ in the Joyal model structure are weakly contractible.
>
> (B) The homotopy fibers of $p$ in the Kan–Quillen model structure are weakly contractible.

It is easy to see that (B) does not imply (A). For instance, consider a cocartesian fibration $p:\mathcal{C}\to\Delta^1$ classifying a morphism $\mathcal{A}\to\Delta^0$ in $\mathcal{C}\mathsf{at}_\infty$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is any $\infty$-category which is not weakly contractible. Then $\mathcal{A}$ is a homotopy fiber of $p$ in the Joyal model structure, so $p$ has a homotopy fiber which is not weakly contractible. But the homotopy fibers of $p$ in the Kan–Quillen model structures are contractible, since $\mathcal{C}$ and $\Delta^1$ are weakly contractible.

However, **I can neither prove nor disprove that (A) implies (B)**. Does anyone know a proof or a counterexample of the implication (A)$\implies$(B)?

Comment: What about $C = \partial \Delta^1$, $D = \Delta^1$, $p$ the inclusion. Do I understand your question right?

Comment: @ReidBarton Oh, that's a perfect example. Could you turn your comment into an answer?